# VB.NET Module code being executed without being executed

Tags: vb.net, exception, module

I inherited a VB.NET project that uses a module to check some user permissions.

One of the functions is called UserLevel and it makes a few calls to a hardware .dll file to read some serial numbers. The function looks like this:

```
Public Function UserLevel() As Integer
    Dim status As Integer = userLevelWrapper.hardware.ReadInteger()
    If status = 0 Then

        If userLevelWrapper.readDaysLeft() > 0 Then
            Return 2 'The user is a temporary user
        Else
            Return 0 'The user is invalid
        End If

    ElseIf Environment.UserName = "User1" OrElse _
           Environment.UserName = "User2" Then 
           'There are more of these, and the user names are obviously not "User1" and "User2" because I've changed them for posting purposes.
        Return 1 'The user is a developer

    Else
        Return 0 'The user is invalid

    End If
End Function
```

For some reason I'm not able to step into this module when debugging. I can't figure out how it's configured, so I've had to make changes as I go and just check the result. I'm just trying to have the module tell my application that I'm a developer so I get uninterrupted use of the app. I've done this successfully by changing the UserLevel function to look like this:

```
Public Function UserLevel() As Integer
    Return 1 'I am a developer

    'All other code remains the same, and is not commented.
End Function
```

Because I don't have that userLevelWrapper package properly installed, I get a FileNotFoundException when actually executing the code. I assumed that happened when the `Dim status As Integer...` line is executed, so I altered that line to be

`Dim status As Integer = 123456789 'userLevelWrapper.hardware.ReadInteger()`

which will obviously force the `If` statement to evaluate to false. When I run it, I still get the FileNotFoundException.

I found out that the function is generating the exception because there *exists* a call to the hardware .dll on the 5th line where it's calling `.readDaysLeft()`, even though it's not being executed. When I comment that line and the `.ReadInteger()` call, no exception is thrown.

My question in this case is two parts: 
1. Why doesn't the exception get thrown when the first line of the function is `Return 1`, and I haven't commented the hardware calls?
2. Why is the module trying to resolve where the file is when code is not being executed?

It makes sense to try to resolve the file at compile-time, but why is it just generating its own rules here by resolving it at run time but only under some arbitrary conditions?

Comment: The just-in-time compiler needs to be able to find the assembly that contains the "userlevelWrapper" class so it can properly compile the method.  It can't find the assembly.  We can't find it for you either.

Comment: What happens if you change status to a `Constant` when you hard-code it to a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not arbitrary.

When the code is commented out, it will not be compiled into the IL code that is translated by the JIT compiler into machine code.

When you don't comment it out, whether that branch of the code is compiled to IL or not becomes a compiler implementation detail that you can't make assumptions about. Maybe it is smart enough to know that branch will never get executed... maybe that analysis costs to much so it doesn't do it. The JIT compiler might compile your code to the machine level at a function level, in which case it will have to compile the entire function to machine code. At that time it'll need to find the assembly containing the function you call and fail.

It is possible that if you change status to a `Constant` the compiler might recognize that there's a branch that will never be executed and optimize it out of the IL.

Comment: I think you're right. I forgot that the compiler will do some optimizations, which is why the function succeeded when I had `Return 1` as the first line. Thanks for the clarification.